# Data type conversion problem

Tags: data-type

I have a Wemos D1 board with a OLED display using the u8g2 library.

I am printing my MAC-adress on the serial port & would like to print the same information on the OLED:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <U8g2lib.h>
byte mac[6];
setup(){
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
  WiFi.macAddress(mac);
  u8g2.drawStr(1,10,WiFi.macAddress());
  u8g2.sendBuffer();
}
```

This does not work. It prints the MAC-address on the serial port but not on the OLED.

I get: no known conversion for argument 3 from 'String' to 'const char*

How can I print the MAC-information on my oled using the u8g2-library?

Comment: Hint: `WiFi.macAddress().c_str()` https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/c_str/

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Mikael Patel
You need to append `.c_str()` to `u8g2.drawStr(1,10,WiFi.macAddress());` creating the line: `u8g2.drawStr(1,10,WiFi.macAddress().c_str());`

The problem is that `WiFi.macAddress()` returns a `String` not the needed `const char*` by the `drawStr` function. `c_str` converts the `String` object into a `const char*`.

Please look at the documentation of the `u8g2` library for the `drawStr` function.

[link](https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2/wiki/u8g2reference#drawstr)

And here the documentation for `String`

[link](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/)